# Do I place a comma before or after "and" in this instance?

Tags: punctuation, commas

What would be correct? Comma before or after 'and'.

"I saw Anne helping him stay functional for as long as possible **and,** in one way or another, felt uplifted."

Answer (score 0):

You can place the comma after the 'and' as you have done.

The part of the sentence between your two commas should be removable from the sentence and it still make sense.

E.g...

> I saw Anne helping him stay functional for as long as possible and, in one way or another, felt uplifted.

becomes...

> I saw Anne helping him stay functional for as long as possible and felt uplifted.